# What container is affected by the ajaxComplete

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have several divs where the AJAX contents are posted on. The **ajaxComplete** is trigerred on all AJAX completes, but I would like to know which of the containers are loaded with the new AJAX content. I'm using this, but it is not working.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
   // loadedDOM is one of the containers where AJAX result is posted on
   var loadedDOM=xhr.responseText.parent();
});
```

What's the best way to know which containers are newly loaded with AJAX results.

Comment: Well for a start, `responseText` is, well, **text** (a string). Strings don't have a `parent` method.

Comment: How are the events being triggered? You should be able to use `this` within the event listener function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have several divs where the AJAX contents are posted on...

Ajax *loads* something from the server, it doesn't post anything anywhere. The `ajaxComplete` call won't be specific to any container `div` because, well, there isn't any.

If you're using the [`load` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/), which is a shorthand method that does an ajax call *and then* puts the result into a given container, the information about what container it puts it in is not propagated to `ajaxComplete` (at least, not according to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)). You'll need to convert those `load` calls into separate `ajax` and `text`/`html` calls (see the details in the `load` documentation) and do something of your own to pass along that information, or write your own wrapper for `load` which uses `load`'s complete handler to pass along that information.

Re your comment:

> is there like a general over arching listener that will capture all loads and find out which of the containers were loaded ?

Not that I know of. You could create your own special `load` function and have it fire a custom event, then handle that custom event at the `document` level:

Add our own "load with event" function (once):<sup>1</sup>

```
jQuery.fn.loadWithEvent = function() {
    var t = this;
    t.load.apply(t, arguments).then(function() {
        t.trigger(jQuery.Event("ajaxload"));
    });
};
```

Add a general handler for that event (once):

```
$(document).on("ajaxload", function(e) {
    // Here, e.target is the element it was fired on
    console.log("got it on document", e.target);
});
```

Using it (as often as needed):

```
$("#target").loadWithEvent("/some/url");
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If you're using ES2015 (aka "ES6"), the `loadWithEvent` function can be a bit simpler:

```
jQuery.fn.loadWithEvent = function(...args) {
    this.load(...args).then(() => {
        this.trigger(jQuery.Event("ajaxload"));
    });
};
```

Comment: I am using the load method. is there like a general over arching  listener that will capture all loads and find out which of the containers were loaded ? assuming no callbacks on the initiating load methods. I've been searching on the net and this topic hasn't been discussed much.

Comment: @jfet93: Not that I know of. I've added a note to the answer about how you might work around that.